# install python healthcareai using anaconda error

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I installed the anaconda on my Win PC

> Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I am getting the following error

```
conda install -c catalyst healthcareai
```

> Solving environment: failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
>   HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.continuum.io\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/pro/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([(\'SSL routines\', \'ssl3_get_server_certificate\', \'certificate verify failed\')],)",),))',),)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a known issue https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-py/issues/400

This can be easily solved installing it with pip rather than conda: `pip install healthcareai`